# Jackson: mixing static/dynamic type handling

Tags: json, jackson

I am using

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
              property="_class")
class Base { }
class Derived1 extends Base { ... }
class Derived2 extends Base { ... }
...
```

to serialize and deserialize a polymorphic base class. This works fine but I am forced to include the _class attribute everywhere in my JSON documents, even in places where the actual types are known at compile time. I have lots of Derived classes (none of which are polymorphic) and lots of JSON documents that I cannot control, so I would like to use dynamic type information *only* if the declared class is actually Base.

Is this possible with Jackson? For example, I would like the following to work:

```
package json_demo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
              include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="_class")
class Base {
   public int baseMember_;
}
class Derived extends Base {
   public int derivedMember_;
}
class Demo {
   public Derived member_;
}
public class Main
{
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
   {
      final String input = "{ \"member_\": { \"baseMember_\":1," 
                         + "\"derivedMember_\":2 } }";
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.readValue(input, Demo.class);  // throws, why?
   }
}
```

The exception I get from from readValue() is

```
JsonMappingException:
Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME:
missing property '_class' that is to contain type id 
(for class json_demo.Derived)
```

Comment: I believe you have to annotate your `Derived` class to override the annotation on `Base`. That way Jackson won't expect the `_class` property.

Answer (score 0):

It says "missing property '_class'", then the json string should be like this:

```
{
    "member_": {
        "_class": "json_demo.Derived",
        "baseMember_": 1,
        "derivedMember_": 2
    }
}
```